# Handle http text/plain reponse in angular js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I need to show `text/plain` response from POST API on GUI. below is my code for http post operation.

```
$http.post("/compare").success(function(data){
        cb(data);
     }).error(function(error){
         eb(error);
     });
```

Getting below error as it is trying to parse response in `json` format.

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token 
    at Object.parse (native)
    at fromJson
```

Actual Response from API, it contains tabs and new line character as well:

```
Response header: content-type:text/plain
Response payload:         
{
  "output": {
    "diff": "
 apples {
     apple 101 {
         conf {
             test {
                 forward {
-                    mac AABB.CCDD.EEFF;
+                    mac B222.2BBB.2222;
                 }
             }
         }
     }
 }
"
}
```

When I tried with jquery ajax call I was able to handle text/plain response from API. **Is there any way to handle text/plain response in angular post?**

Comment: `cb(JSON.parse(data));` parse it if it is json string.

Comment: @Jai, I assume this is not a valid json either..

Comment: You can try to set `responseType` property of $http https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#usage

Comment: @RayonDabre but OP says it worked with jQuery.

Comment: The "diff" variable is a string, and his content not is JSON... you need to parse this string, it's a specific diff format.

Answer (score 0):

The payload is one trailing `}` short of being valid JSON. Did you format/cut the result wrong or is this really the (invalid) result?

That said, the `data` you get in your success callback will just be a string, so as someone mentioned in the comments, you need to parse the string to get a valid javascript object out of it:

```
cb(JSON.parse(data));
```

Check out this example:
https://fiddle.jshell.net/o6s37mha/ and open your console (hit F12 before you run it) if you want to see the difference.